# Which armor special abilities can be applied to Bracers of Armor?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, armor

The [Bracers of Armor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bracers-of-armor) page states:

> Bracers of armor cannot have any armor special abilities that add a flat gp amount to their cost.

And, a [Q&A with Jason Bulmahn](https://paizo.com/community/blog/v5748dyo5ldpy?Ultimate-Equipment-Preview-Oh-For-a-Muse-of-Fire#7) clarified that Bracers of Armor do not count as any wieght class of armor, so any ability that specifies that it can only be put on light/medium/heavy armor can't be put on Bracers of Armor.

With those restrictions in mind, which [Armor Special Abilities](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/) **can** you put on Bracers of Armor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I went through the [list of abilities](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/) and found them.

**+1 Armor Special Abilities**

Benevolent, Billowing, Bitter, Calming, Champion, Cocooning, Crusading, Dastard, Deathless, Defiant, Evolving, Fortification (light), Grinding, Impervious, Poisoning, Spell Storing, Spellsink, Stanching, Vouchsafing, Warding

**+2 Armor Special Abilities**

Frosted, Ghost Spike, Jarring, Shadow Blending, Spell Dodging, Spell Resistance (13)

**+3 Armor Special Abilities**

Cotravelling, Fortification (moderate), Ghost Touch, Invulnerability, Sensing, Spell Resistance (15), Titanic, Wild

**+4 Armor Special Abilities**

Spell Resistance (17)

**+5 Armor Special Abilities**

Fortification (heavy), Spell Resistance (19)

Of the 122 Shield and Armor abilities, only 36 are applicable, and even then some of them make very little sense to have on the bracers, like Titanic, Poisoning, and Impervious.

Comment: According to your FAQ the fortification ones should not be on this list

Comment: Where does it say that Fortification can't be applied to Bracers? If you're referring to what Zaistar said in the thread, I remind you that the Bracers of Armor page specifically says that it can be enchanted with armor special abilities.

Comment: @hamburgerpis clarified that Bracers of Armor do not count as any wieght class of armor, so any ability that specifies that it can only be put on light/medium/heavy armor can't be put on Bracers of Armor. So since the fortification can only be put on specific weight categories, its not valid for bracers.

Comment: Light/Moderate/Heavy Fortification refers to the potency of the Fortification ability, not the weight class of the armor. Light Fortification has a 25% chance to negate crits/sneak attacks, Moderate has 50%, and Heavy has 75%.

Comment: I was positive that armor couldnt have a stronger form than its weight, but I dont see that online now. Im very sorry, you were correct.